# How do I create a formula in excel that searches for a value in row, and then takes the value from another cell in that column?

Tags: excel, vba

Im Trying to write a formula in excel that would basically say: IF you find in **row15** the cell showing ***!***, THEN copy the **date** value assigned at the top of that column in **Row2** to a new cell.
Im not knowledgeable enough on excel to write the formula in the right language.

[Here's the Gantt chart I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LAVZ.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($2:$2,MATCH("!",15:15,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a range of cells to a variable first, then reference it and use the `countif` function to see if a certain value is in range. Then you could use an IF statement to see if the value from countif is true. And if it is, then print whatever you want.

```
range = F4:F10    # for example
=COUNTIF(range,'!')>0    #This returns true if it contains !
```

then you could throw in an if statement like this to print something if true

```
=IF(COUNTIF(range,'!'),"Yes","No")    #It will print yes if the range contains '!'
```

You can change the yes and no outputs to print a certain cell if you want.